# Select Current Quarter From Quarter Dates table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table:

| Quarter Start |
| --- |
| 30/12/2016 |
| 31/03/2017 |
| 30/06/2017 |
| 29/09/2017 |
| 29/12/2017 |
| 30/03/2018 |
| 29/06/2018 |
| 28/09/2018 |
| 28/12/2018 |
| 29/03/2019 |
| 28/06/2019 |
| 27/09/2019 |
| 27/12/2019 |
| 27/03/2020 |
| 26/06/2020 |
| 25/09/2020 |
| 01/01/2021 |
| 02/04/2021 |
| 02/07/2021 |
| 01/10/2021 |
| 31/12/2021 |
| 01/04/2022 |
| 01/07/2022 |
| 30/09/2022 |
| 30/12/2022 |
| 24/03/2023 |
| 30/06/2023 |
| 29/09/2023 |
| 29/12/2023 |
| 29/03/2024 |
| 28/06/2024 |
| 27/09/2024 |
| 03/01/2025 |
| 04/04/2025 |
| 03/10/2025 |
| 02/01/2026 |
| 03/04/2026 |
| 03/07/2026 |
| 02/10/2026 |
| 01/01/2027 |
| 02/04/2027 |
| 02/07/2027 |
| 01/10/2027 |

What can I write to always select the current quarter according to this table and the current date? For eg the current quarter is '09/12/2022', how can I always ensure to select the current quarter?

Many thanks

UPDATE: I have run by some of the suggestions as follows

```
SELECT 
    quarter_start,
    EXTRACT (QUARTER FROM quarter_start)
FROM
    odwh_work.sdc_2027
WHERE
    EXTRACT (QUARTER FROM quarter_start) =  EXTRACT (QUARTER FROM current_date)
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

But I am still not returning 2022-12-09

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to find the date which both matches the current quarter and the current year. This can be done so:

```
SELECT yourdate FROM yourtable 
WHERE EXTRACT('quarter' FROM yourdate) =  EXTRACT('quarter' FROM now())
AND EXTRACT('year' FROM yourdate) = EXTRACT('year' FROM now());
```

This query can of course find multiple dates when they satisfy these conditions. If you want to find only the latest of them, use `MAX`:

```
SELECT MAX(yourdate) FROM yourtable 
WHERE EXTRACT('quarter' FROM yourdate) =  EXTRACT('quarter' FROM now())
AND EXTRACT('year' FROM yourdate) = EXTRACT('year' FROM now());
```

See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7pCYz19f)

Comment: This is along the lines of what I'm looking for, however, I think that the system definition of quarter is different to the definition of Quarter starts I have in my table. I see the logic in your answer, but I need to precisely return 2022-12-30 not 2022-12-31

Comment: For your data, the query will return your date.

Comment: Ah yes you are right, it is returning the correct date, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have many rows you can

```
select * from foo where extract('quarter' from 'Quarter Start') = extract('quarter' from now());
```

But beware that this can't utilize an index on a date since quarter (1,2,3,4) is not a date in itself but a digit.

```
create table stack (id serial, quarter date);
insert into stack (quarter) values ('2022-09-15');
insert into stack (quarter) values ('2022-10-10');

select * from stack;
 id |  quarter   
----+------------
  2 | 2022-09-15
  3 | 2022-10-10

select * from stack where extract('quarter' from quarter) = extract('quarter' from now());
 id |  quarter   
----+------------
  3 | 2022-10-10
```

Comment: thanks - I have tried running this but it doesnt return 2022-12-30. I will update my question with what I have written

Comment: Hi, a bit unsure what you mean. I have updated the answer, is this useful?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you expect, but you can get the quarter by extracting it:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(quarter from '30/12/2022'::date)
```